# IE6 background image not displaying

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am trying to style ie6 for the people that are still for whatever reason using this browser. The problem I am having, is that the background-image is not displaying. The path is correct and when I put in full path in browser the image displays. Where have I gone wrong in my code. Thanks

```
.buttonMailTrue:hover {
    background-image: url('http://localhost/sample/users/images/mail_icon_strip_hover.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:290px;
    height:44px;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE6 supports :hover on links only. So you have to do something like this:

CSS:

```
.buttonMailTrue.hover {
    background-image: url('http://localhost/sample/users/images/mail_icon_strip_hover.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:290px;
    height:44px;
    color: black;
}
```

Javascript(with jQuery):

```
$('.buttonMailTrue').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: I have tried in head and in external js file and still not working.

Answer (score 4):

Hover only works for links in ie6.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried in head and in external js file and still not working.

try the internal `<script type="text/javascript" rel="JavaScript">//code here</script>`

Comment: Still not working. I have changed the image to png changed the order of the css so color is first and use relative path as opposed to absolute.

Comment: lay it out as a function like "function start(){$('.buttonMailTrue').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});}" and then in the body tag put onload=start()